# heroku remote connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to retrieve records from an online mysql wordpress database into a ruby on rails application using the table model. The method uses mysql2 gem which I added to the gem file and seems to at least load. The code to connect is

```
require "rest-client"

require "mysql2"

mnosql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "ip-address",  :username => "user",  :password => "password",  :database => "minnesu5_name")
```

The heroku log says that it cant connect to the database at ip and there is a request time out
I  am using the QuotaGuard for a static IP and verified that the Quotaguardstatic returns an IP which I have added to the remote mysql access list. I have verified that this code and connection works in Dev but not on Heroku.

Comment: Please at least format your code